# SQL query to retrieve product details from same city as of agent is living

Tags: sql

The following problem was asked in an exam I took, but I could not come up with an answer.
Could someone please help me to understand how to work it out?

Tables schema:-

```
CUSTOMERS
------------
cid       PK
cname
city
discount

AGENTS
------------
aid       PK
aname
city
percent

PRODUCTS
------------
pid       PK
pname
city
quantity
price

ORDERS
------------
ordno     PK
month
cid
aid
pid
qty
dollars
```

1. Get pnames and pids of products that are stored in the same city as one of the agents
   who sold these products
2. Get pids of products ordered by all customers with any orders placed through agent
   "a03"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st Question**

First of all we select needed information from table

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.pid, p.pname 
FROM Products AS p
```

Then we look how is Agents and Products are connected, they are connected through table Orders
we do join with this table to get Agents ids

```
INNER JOIN Orders AS o ON (o.pid = p.pid)
```

Then we need get Agents data, with condition that Agent city is the same as Product storage city

```
INNER JOIN Agents AS t ON (o.aid = a.aid AND p.city = a.city)
```

Then we get query

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.pid, p.pname 
FROM Products AS p
INNER JOIN Orders AS o ON (o.pid = p.pid)
INNER JOIN Agents AS t ON (o.aid = a.aid AND p.city = a.city)
```

Which gets us needed answer.

**2nd Question**

Again we query needed data from table

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.pid
FROM Products AS p
INNER JOIN Orders AS o ON (o.pid = p.pid)
INNER JOIN Agents AS t ON (o.aid = a.aid)
WHERE a.aname = 'a03'
```

Just adding where condition.

All this examples work on MySQL. 
If you are looking where to experiment on SQL queries I suggest [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) 
and for reading and learning maybe [W3Schools SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)